# Excel formula does not return results till cell format is changed to "Text"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to return some nested IF formula results, but my result cell stays blank till I change its format to "text". How can I obtain the results without changing the cell format every time I perform the calculation?

As an example,

=IF(B2 = 1, "Bad", IF(B2 = 2, "Good", IF(B2 = 3, "Excellent", "NA")))

returns "Excellent".

However, the cell remains blank, it only prints "Excellent" when I change the cell format from "Custom" to "Text".

Comment: Please post formula/input that you are using along with the output that you need.

Comment: You can clear all formatting from resulting cells then put formula.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work